# Laravel 7 - How to insert multiple data to mysql database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into database. But i don't know how to insert multi select checkbox data into the mysql database.

- Controller

```
    public function create(Request $request)
        {
            try { 
                
                $id_student = $request->get('id_student');
                   
                $consecutive = DB::select('SELECT SUM(idRecord) FROM record GROUP BY idRecord');
                $final_consecutive = sprintf("%04d", $consecutive); 
        
                foreach($request->select as $data)
                {
                    Records::create($data);
                }
    
                return back()->with('success', 'Constancia creada correctamente');
        
            } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
                if (strpos($message, "Duplicate entry")) {
                    return back()->with('err', 'Esta constancia ya ha sido creada');
                }
                if (strpos($message, "1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'idGrupo'")) {
                    return back()->with('err', 'Debe seleccionar un grupo para poder continuar');
                }
                return back()->with('err', $message);
            }
        }
```

- View

```
    @foreach ($group->students as $student)
        <tr>
           <td class="align-middle text-center">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" value="{{$student->lastName}} {{$student->Names}}" disabled>
            </td>
    
            <td class="align-middle text-center">
                 <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="grade" value="{{isset($student->pivot->grade)?$student->pivot->grade:''}}" placeholder="grade" disabled>
             </td>
    
    
            <form action="{{url('/Create/Records')}}" method="POST">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="hidden" name="id_student" value="{{$student->id_student}}" >
                    <td class="align-middle text-center">
                        <input id="select" type="checkbox" name="select[]">
                    </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Save</button>
        </div>
```

What I tried to do was use a select checkbox and then in the Controller I passed it as an array in the foreach loop, but honestly I think I'm nowhere close to figuring it out... Other than that the consecutive is automatically generated and I don't know how to pass it to the array as well.

I get this error by the way:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create()
> must be of the type array, string given

[image: records]

Comment: If you check your for loop, $request->select it will give you a string, not an key value pair array. That's why it is throwing this error. Can you share Record model structure?

Comment: Ok, I edited the post and added the image of my table records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass data to your Model like:

```
Records::create(['id_student' => $idStudent, 'consecutive' => $consecutive]);
```

Currently, you are giving like:

```
Records::create('string');
```

Which is not correct way to pass the data. That's why getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create() take array as parameter.
When your foreach loop execute $data value 0 or 1 as string so that why error is given.

if you want to create in foreach loop then

```
foreach($request->select as $data)
{
    Records::create(['field_name' => $data]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by default multiple select checkbox will be converted to assoc array with name that ends with [] as its key for example your using so you can access it like:

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
```

then you can iterate through the values this is a plain php would suggest to use the laravel method as it offers more like security and filter this one is a simple and fast solution. But if you using an ajax submission you should always make sure that the parameter always ends with [] example you have a get request but still the same syntax applies to post method:

```
http://localhost?select[]=1&select[]=2
```

the same code will work as on top but for get request like this you will use:

```
$select = $_GET['select'];
```

haven't tried on laravel request object but I think the same conversion is being done when your using the Request instance you may try that as well just make sure you always end the parameter name with [] but if the name of all the checkbox is set to select it will just return a single string which the error means.